# How to get timezone from QDateTime

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to get the time zone date using `QDateTime`, what I expect is something like 2018-03-19T00:00:00-02:00 but what I get is 2019-10-27T19:56:09-2147483648

```
QDateTime dh = QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc();
QString dataHoraEmi = dh.toString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss");
dataHoraEmi.append(dh.timeZone().offsetData(dh).standardTimeOffset);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution could be:

```
QDateTime dh = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
QString dataHoraEmi = dh.toTimeZone(dh.timeZone()).toString(Qt::ISODate);
```

Possible output:

> "2019-10-28T13:29:49+01:00"